# How to save logs in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to read logs from the output window in WP8. If i run windows phone application on Visual Studio, i see logs in output window. But if i run application on windows phone without Visual Studio, i cannot see logs. And i can't read this logs. I don't want to write my own logging system, I want to read the data from OUTPUT. And i want to read this data in Release configuration.

I tried to redirect `Console.Out` to a file, but it still not work.
`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` doesn't work in Release Configuration.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As far I know, logging for these types of devices is done through remote debugging session. And keep a log on such type of device incorrectly by definition. So it was before, at least.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is to write your logs to IsolatedStorage.
If you are not willing to do so,click the link below you can use it directly:

http://wpclogger.codeplex.com/downloads/get/374016

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write logs to files(.txt,..) to Isolated Storage and load it if you want to read detail.

Comment: I know that. But i want to read logs from output window (with system logs about exceptions etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In fact it works.

Steps to follow :

1. Goto Project properties.
2. Select the "Build" option in the right pane.
3. Choose "Release" option from the dropdown box of Configuration.
4. Under "General" section below in the same "Build" pane select checkboxes.

   ---

   - **Define TRACE constant**      *&*      **Define DEBUG constant**

---

5. Close the Project properties.

Next goto "Tools" menu

1. Select "Options" at the end of menu.
2. In the "Options" dialog > Expand Debugging branch
3. Select "General"
4. Unselect "Enable Just My Code" checkbox.

Now either deploy to device or run in the emulator.